# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2{n \choose k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How should I do this proof? should induction be used?

So far I have thought about using:

$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$

but I cant break up that summation so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You should use the search engine before asking a question.

Comment: I usually only ask when I have tried searching for and failed in finding an answer, since I know that stackexchange it not at all tolerant about duplicate questions (case in point), not sure why I couldn't find that post though.

Comment: Also think of selecting $k$ people from a population of $n$ and giving out two awards (possibly both to the same lucky person). The sum for all $k$ from $0$ to $n$ can be counted using both sides of the equation (with some algebraic manipulation on the right).

Comment: It´s not a big problem posting a duplicate,especially if you tried your best. You can see on the linked site that there are several links to questions with equal topic but partly different approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial theorem gives that
$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k} = (x+y)^n.$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ and multiplying by $x$ gives
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} k x^k y^{n-k} = nx(x+y)^{n-1}.$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ and multiplying by $x$ again gives
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} k^2 x^k y^{n-k} = nx(x+y)^{n-1} + n(n-1)x^2(x+y)^{n-2}.$$
Setting $x = y = 1$ gives
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} k^2 = n 2^{n-1} + n(n-1)2^{n-2} =n(n+1)2^{n-2},$$
as you were trying to show.

Comment: Thanks! clear and precise answer, better than the suggested duplicate to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k = (1+x)^n$ and $(xD)^2 x^k|_{x=1} = k^2 x^k|_{x=1}=k^2$, where $D = d/dx$.